# how to get alert when RSI cross down 30 level and price cross 50% cross

Tags: pine-script

when RSI go down 30 below i want to save this bar_index number

then if until next 3 bars if Close price cross 50% of previous saved bar_index candle

then i want to get alert.

but i still confusing my approaching using bar_index is correct or not.

anyone help me appreciate!

here is sample example pic and code

```
//@version=5
indicator("rsi",overlay = true)
r = ta.rsi(close, 14)  
checkcrossed = ta.crossunder(r, 30)

var barNo = 0
if checkcrossed and bar_index < 3000 // limited bar_index to 2000 and when r cross down 30 save this bar's bar_index for reference later. 
    barNo := bar_index
    
alertbar = open - (open - close) * 0.5   // calculate middle price of current bar
label.new(bar_index, low * 0.995, str.tostring(alertbar))
if close > alertbar[barNo]
    alert('alert')
```

if remove bar_index number limit 3000 it return some error . have no idea what wrong with it.

[image]